# Edit User Permissions Disabled in Ribbon

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, ribbon

In this particular site, I am unable to modify the Group permissions. As you can see, the buttons are disabled in the Ribbon.

[image]

Why are these disabled if I have full control and am a Global admin? Other sites they are not disabled, is it the template being used?

Comment: Are you Site collection administrator? Is inheritance is broken in this site?

Comment: Yes, there is a Private Doc library with broken inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to back door the Edit Permissions page, which means it's not a security issue but a UI bug.

I took the URL from another Site Collection (communication site) where the 'Edit Permissions' ribbon button is not greyed out, and replaced a couple things in the URL to point to the 'broken' site:

```
https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{replacedthis}/_layouts/15/editprms.aspx?obj=https%3A%2F%2{tenant}%2Esharepoint%2Ecom%2Fsites%2F{replacedthis}%2CWEB&sel=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Per my test in my SharePoint online environment, if the user has the full control in the site, then he can modify the permission of the group.

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Check user permission of the current user in the site.
2. Switch to other browsers to check if the same issue will occur.

Comment: Thanks for running your test. I'm definitely admin and it's the result same in IE9 and Chrome. Did you test with a Modern Team site ?